# JAVA: The method is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, array, poo

Estoy creando un programa que se trata sobre comparar elementos de dos listas y generar una tercera con dichos elementos cumpliendo ciertas condiciones (Si ambos elemento situados en las listas se colocan en la nueva lista, sino, sucede otra funcion...).

Este es mi código y el error es en "`lstC.add("-"+ValorA);`"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
//
public class GenerarLista {
    ArrayList<ConceptosLista> lstA = new ArrayList<ConceptosLista>();
    ArrayList<ConceptosLista> lstB = new ArrayList<ConceptosLista>();
    ArrayList<ConceptosLista> lstC = new ArrayList<ConceptosLista>();

    public  void agregarConceptos(ConceptosLista objConceptos){
        lstC.add(objConceptos);
    }
    public String Listar(){
        for(ConceptosLista ValorA: lstA) {
            if(!ValorA.equals(" ")){
                if(lstB.contains(ValorA)){
                    lstC.add(ValorA);
                }else{
                    lstC.add("-"+ValorA);
                }
            }

        } 

        //

        return null;
    }

}
```

Y el error que me resulta es:

> The method add(ConceptosLista) in the type ArrayList
>   is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Y mi clase "ConceptosLista" consta de estos atributos:

```
public class ConceptosLista {
    private String posicion;
    private String numeroParte;
    private String descripcion;
    private double monto;
    private String cambioPrecio;
    private String concepto;
    private double montoConvenio;


    public ConceptosLista(String posicion, String numeroParte, String descripcion, double monto, String cambioPrecio,
            String concepto, double montoConvenio) {
        this.posicion = posicion;
        this.numeroParte = numeroParte;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.monto = monto;
        this.cambioPrecio = cambioPrecio;
        this.concepto = concepto;
        this.montoConvenio = montoConvenio;
    }


}
```

Gracias, espero me puedan ayudar.

Funciones:

```
//Primer for compara los valores de la lista A CON LA LISTA B
     for (String valorA : a){
         //Si son iguales los agrega directo a mi nueva lista C
         if(!valorA.equals(" ")){
             if(b.contains(valorA)){
                 c.add(valorA);
                 //Si no, los agrega pero con "-"
             }else{
                 c.add("-"+valorA);
             }
         }
     }

//Aplicar cada funcion para cada elemento de la lista

     for (String valorB : b){
         if(!valorB.equals(" ")){
             if(!a.contains(valorB)){
                 c.add("+"+valorB);
             }
         }
     }

//Este for manda imprimir la lista C
     for (String valorC : c){
         System.out.print(valorC+" ");
     }
```

Comment: `ValorA` no es un `String` para que intentes agregarle esto: `"-"`. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer: `lstC.add("-"+ValorA);`? Dices que *Si ambos elemento situados en las listas se colocan en la nueva lista, sino, sucede otra funcion...*  pero no sucede esa *otra función*, sino que intentas algo indebido: agregar el caracter `-` al elemento.

Comment: Ese for each me compara de la lstA y lstB si son iguales los datos, de caso contrario se agregan a una nueva lista C (lstC) pero diferenciandolos con un "-".

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de agragar las funciones que cree mediante un algoritmo aparte, solo que lo aplico en otro programa y me resulta ese error.

Comment: ¿Cómo diferenciándolos con un `-`?  Como te dije, no es una cadena a la cual le puedas agregar un `-`, es un objeto. Me parece que estás emprendiendo un planteamiento muy confuso del problema. Lo que tienes ahí es un array de objetos, si quieres diferenciar algo tendrás que cambiar alguna propiedad del objeto, o agregar otra cosa al array, el cual contendrá el objeto y *esa otra cosa que quieres que lo diferencie*.

Answer (score 2):

El error es porqué el objeto que le entregas es tipo String y no del tipo que indicaste que acepta al momento de instanciarlo (Ex: `List<Object> a = new List()`)
y la función [add(E)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) solo acepta objetos de la clase indicada.
en este caso la Clase **ConceptosLista**, y valorA es un objeto de la clase ConceptosLista pero deja de serlo al agregarle el signo de la forma que lo haces.

> "-"+valorA

Al concatenar un String a un objeto, la JVM llama la función [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) del objeto, lo cual resulta en un objeto de la clase String.

dicho esto, si necesitas diferenciarlo, lo que puedes hacer es añadirle una función a la Clase ConceptosLista que reciba este signo "+" o "-" y el cual pueda ser visto en el toString de la clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias dude, lo tomaré en cuenta!